# How to filterd mail domain from the list of emails using hibernate query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, hibernate

I have a list of emais data like `abc@gmail.com`, `abc@yahoo.com`, `asd@gmail.com`, `asd@yahoo.com`, `sdf@gmail.com`.

Now i want to filter email domain list as 'gmail', all data should be filter and shown only list of gmail id's not other email id's.

my code is:

```
List<String> EmaiList = (List<String>) session.createQuery("select email from UserDto where email like :lk and type" +
                        (isMailStuff ? " in (:mailTypes)" : " not in (:mailTypes)"))
                        .setString("lk", partEmail + "%")
                        .setParameterList("mailTypes", UserType.mailTypes)
                        .list();
```

In this code , i have set isMailStuff is 'true'. Now i can filter gmail list but some places i can see other mail id also like yahoo mail id's.

Can you please let me know any chnages are required in this query.

Regards,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

add

```
where substring_index(email_column, '@', -1)='gmail.com'
```

Comment: :- am very poor on hibernate ..can i know where to add this code?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `setString` to this

```
.setString("lk", "%" + partEmail + "%")
```

where the value of `partEmail` is `@gmail`, it will return you the list of emails containing the pattern `@gmail`.

Comment: If i given input of partEmail as 'a', it should be display the list of mail id's (gmail) which have letter 'a'. In this case the above setString is not working. Can you have some other idea about it.

Comment: `above setString is not working`? it is returning all the emails having `a` in them.. right?

Comment: Yes Debojit, it is returning all email list which is having 'a'

Comment: it means its working as expected.you are defining a pattern and it is returning emails containing that pattern. this is what you want .. right?

Comment: No Debojit, My req is if i enter 'a' all the emails (only gmail) should be display . but if other emails are also contains 'a' like yahoo email id's should not be displayed. I cannot search by domain like gmail.com or yahoo.com , and can only search by the name before the domain like abc, asd.

Comment: So the `pattern` with which you execute the query is different from the `partEmail` value. Do you have any mapping defined? Like if `partEmail` is `a`, look for `gmail`.If `partEmail` is `b`, look for `yahoo`..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38411/discussion-between-ravi-k-chowdary-and-debojit-saikia)